# Static analysis tool for C programs

Tags: static, analysis, cppcheck

I'm looking for Static Analysis open-source tool for these,

1. Checking the return value of the function.

   ```
   foobar = Get_FooBar(...); //this function could return null pointer. 
   foobar->property = value;  //no null check here!
   ```
2. Pointer returned by `malloc`.

   ```
   foobar = (void *)malloc(..);
   foobar->property = value; //return value of malloc is not checked.
   ```

cppcheck doesn't capture this, AFAIK. 
Any other open-source/freeware you folks recommend?

Answer (score 1):

[List of tools for static code analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis)

[Static Source Code Analysis Tools for C](http://spinroot.com/static/)

[Splint](http://splint.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [PVS-Studio](http://viva64.com)
it's not free but you can use free trial (without filling any forms) to find memory issues.